# JS Switching volume through keypress not working

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

So I am trying to make a volume switcher that I can use by pressing UP and DOWN arrow keys on my keyboard.

When I try and log the new volume it has to be set to, this works fine, it gives me the correct value, but then when I try to set my volume on the `<audio>` element it does not appear to be working.

Below is my HTML Code:

```
        <audio id="music" controls autoplay>
            <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
```

The src for the `<source>` element gets set in a different javascript, it will grab a random audio file.

Below here is my Javascript code:

```
let music_element = document.getElementById("music");

function setVolume(volume) {
    music_element.volume = volume;
}

function getVolume() {
    var volume = music_element.volume;
    return volume;
}


document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 38:
            var current_volume = getVolume();
            var new_volume = current_volume + 0.1;
            if (new_volume > 1) {
                new_volume = 1;
            }
            setVolume(new_volume.toFixed(1))
            console.log('Set volume to ' + new_volume.toFixed(1));
            break;
        case 40:
            var current_volume = getVolume();
            var new_volume = current_volume - 0.1;
            if (new_volume < 0) {
                new_volume = 0;
            }
            setVolume(new_volume.toFixed(1))
            console.log('Set volume to ' + new_volume.toFixed(1));
            break;
    }
};
```

[image: Console Output when pressing UP and Down array]

Any help/feedback would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me, here's a snippet you could have used in your question. Only difference is the part that sets the `src` to the `music_element`. Test if that part works for you.

```js
let music_element = document.getElementById("music");

function setVolume(volume) {
  music_element.volume = volume;
}

function getVolume() {
  var volume = music_element.volume;
  return volume;
}


document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 38:
      var current_volume = getVolume();
      var new_volume = current_volume + 0.1;
      if (new_volume > 1) {
        new_volume = 1;
      }
      setVolume(new_volume.toFixed(1))
      console.log('Set volume to ' + new_volume.toFixed(1));
      break;
    case 40:
      var current_volume = getVolume();
      var new_volume = current_volume - 0.1;
      if (new_volume < 0) {
        new_volume = 0;
      }
      setVolume(new_volume.toFixed(1))
      console.log('Set volume to ' + new_volume.toFixed(1));
      break;
  }
};
```

```html
<h3>use arrow keys</h3>
<audio id="music" controls autoplay>
    <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Mains_hum_60_Hz.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your code is fine<sup>✼</sup>, a more likely reason that you have no sound is that you might have sound blocked by the browser. In Chrome do the following:

1. Open the menu and click "Settings".
2. Next click "Privacy and security".
3. Then click "Site settings".
4. Click "Additional content settings".
5. Finally click "Sound" (see screenshot below)

[image].

<sup>✼ There is a minor discrepancy in that `.keyCode` property is deprecated. Use `.key` instead. (see **Example**)</sup>

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference <audio>
const player = document.querySelector("#player");

// Bind the "keydown" event to the Document Object
document.onkeydown = setVolume;

// "keydown" event handler passes the (event) Object by default
function setVolume(event) {
  /*
   * Get the volume of audio#player and multiply it by 10 so
   * it's a whole number which is easier to increment.
   */
  let vol = player.volume * 10;
  /*
   * Event Object .key property will return a string that 
   * represents the key clicked on the keyboard.
   * Increment/decrement "vol" accordingly.
   */
  if (event.key === "arrowUp") {
    vol++;
  }
  if (event.key === "arrowDown") {
    vol--;
  }
  /*
   * If "vol" is less than 0 return 0
   * else if "vol" is greater than 1 return 1
   * otherwise return the original number.
   */
  vol = vol < 0 ? 0 : vol > 1 ? 1 : vol;
  // Multiply "vol" by .1 to keep it within a range of 0 to 1
  player.volume = vol * .1;
}
```

```html
<audio id="player" src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/chinese-gong-daniel_simon.mp3" controls auto></audio>
```